# loadXML does not work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, xml, safari, load

I'm using Safari for windows. It tells me that document.prototype.loadXML is undefined. 
What are my other options to create XML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp (reformatted a bit):

> The following code loads and parses an XML string:
>
> ```
> function loadXML(text)
> {
>     var xmlDocument = null;
>
>     // Internet Explorer
>     try
>     {
>         xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
>         xmlDocument.async = false;
>         xmlDocument.loadXML(text);
>     }
>     // Standards-compliant method.
>     catch (exception)
>     {
>         parser      = new DOMParser();
>         xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
>     }
>
>     return xmlDocument;
> }
> ```
>
> **Note:** Internet Explorer uses the `loadXML()` method to parse an XML string, while other browsers use the `DOMParser` object.